# ERROR: column "int4" specified more than once

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Steps for Execution:

1. Table Creation

   ```
   CREATE TABLE xyz.table_a(
      id bigint NOT NULL,
      scores jsonb,
      CONSTRAINT table_a_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
   );
   ```

   Add some dummy data :

   ```
   INSERT INTO xyz.table_a(
   id, scores)
   VALUES (1, '{"a":20,"b":20}');
   ```
2. Function Creation

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xyz.example(
      table_name text,
      regular_columns text,
      json_column text,
      view_name text
   ) RETURNS text
       LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
       COST 100
       VOLATILE
   AS $BODY$
   DECLARE
      cols TEXT;
      cols_sum TEXT;
   BEGIN
      EXECUTE
         format(
            $ex$SELECT string_agg(
                          format(
                             'CAST(%2$s->>%%1$L AS INTEGER)',
                             key),
                          ', '
                       )
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT key
                      FROM %1$s, jsonb_each(%2$s)
                      ORDER BY 1
                     ) s;$ex$,
            table_name, json_column
         )
      INTO cols;

      EXECUTE
         format(
            $ex$SELECT string_agg(
                          format(
                             'CAST(%2$s->>%%1$L AS INTEGER)',
                             key
                          ),
                          '+'
                       )
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT key
                      FROM %1$s, jsonb_each(%2$s)
                      ORDER BY 1) s;$ex$,
            table_name, json_column
         )
      INTO cols_sum;

      EXECUTE
         format(
            $ex$DROP VIEW IF EXISTS %2$s;
                CREATE VIEW %2$s AS
                SELECT %3$s, %4$s, SUM(%5$s) AS total
                FROM %1$s
                GROUP BY %3$s$ex$,
            table_name, view_name, regular_columns, cols, cols_sum
         );

      RETURN cols;
   END
   $BODY$:
   ```
3. Call Function

   ```
   SELECT xyz.example(
      'xyz.table_a',
      ' id',
      'scores',
      'xyz.view_table_a'
   );
   ```

Once you run these steps, I am getting an error

```
ERROR:  column "int4" specified more than once
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS xyz.view_table_a;
CREATE VIEW xyz.view_table_a AS
SELECT  id, CAST(scores->>'a' AS INTEGER), CAST(scores->>'b' AS INTEGER), SUM(CAST(scores->>'a' AS INTEGER)+CAST(scores->>'b' AS INTEGER)) AS total FROM xyz.table_a GROUP BY  id
```

Comment: When you create a view, each column must have a unique name.

Comment: yes, my columns have unique names. Column names are id, cols, and cols_sum

Comment: When I tried to mention the column name for  %4$s as abc in my function creation, the query runs perfectly but the output view having a column name with int4.

Comment: Your [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) made me have a closer look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the error message closely:

```sql
...
SELECT  id, CAST(scores->>'a' AS INTEGER), CAST(scores->>'b' AS INTEGER),
...
```

There are multiple expressions without column alias. A named column like "id" defaults to the given name. But other expressions default to the internal type name, which is "int4" for `integer`. One might assume that the JSON key name is used, but that's not so. `CAST(scores->>'a' AS INTEGER)` is just another expression returning an unnamed integer value.

This still works for a plain `SELECT`. Postgres tolerates duplicate column names in the (outer) `SELECT` list. But a [`VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) cannot be created that way. Would result in ambiguities.

Either add column aliases to expressions in the `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT id, CAST(scores->>'a' AS INTEGER) AS a, CAST(scores->>'b' AS INTEGER) AS b, ...
```

Or add a list of column names to `CREATE VIEW`:

```
CREATE VIEW xyz.view_table_a(id, a, b, ...) AS ...
```

Something like this should fix your function (preserving literal spelling of JSON key names:

```
...
                       format(
                          'CAST(%2$s->>%%1$L AS INTEGER) AS %%1$I',
                          key),
...
```

See the working demo here:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=515397b661160fc8b1ddc305f09a4508)*

Aside, your nested `format()` calls make the code pretty hard to read and maintain.